# Is request_finished a non-blocking signal?

Tags: django

Django documentation says that `request_finished` signal is sent when Django finishes delivering an HTTP response to the client. Does that mean any operation can be done after the request-response cycle being finished. Is it a non-blocking and asynchronous signal?

Comment: All of Django's signals are synchronous, so if you run some operation in the `request_finished` signal the user would have gotten their response but the operation will take up the thread that was used.